# Error accessing GCP Cloud Storage public object

Tags: node.js, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, node-libcurl

I'm getting following error while reading SSL cert file from GCP Cloud Storage.

```
* Connected to [my.website.com] (A.b.C.D) port 443 (#0)
* found 6 certificates in /home/<username>/[CAINFO].crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* error reading X.509 key or certificate file: Error while reading file.
* Closing connection 0
Error: SSL connect error
    at Error (native)
file."
```

Here's what I'm doing.

1. In NodeJS code, I'm pinging an API end point while authenticating with SSL certs
2. I have an SSL cert stored in GCP Cloud Storage and made it Public (just for testing) following instructions given [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).
3. Instructions to access this object is given [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data).
4. Using `gsutil`, I am able to access the cert.

   `$ gsutil ls -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[SSLCERT].pem` `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[SSLCERT].pem`
5. When I access the SSL cert from NodeJS code, I get above error. The URL to access the file is: `http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[SSLCERT].pem`
6. Instead of Cloud Storage, if I access the cert from local disk and run NodeJS code, it works fine. So, the cert is valid.

Outline of my code:

```
const Curl = require('node-libcurl').Curl;
const curl = new Curl();

const URL = 'https://api-end-point.com';

// let sslcert = '/home/path/to/[SSLCERT].pem';  << this works
let sslcert = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[SSLCERT].pem';  << NOT working

curl.setOpt('URL', URL);
... 
curl.setOpt('SSLCERT', sslcert);
... 

curl.on('end', function(statusCode, body, headers) {

    console.info("Status Code: " + statusCode);
    console.info(body.length);
    this.close();
}); 

curl.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
}); 

curl.perform();
```

Comment: So, you're expecting that `http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[SSLCERT].pem` to download a file?  Does it, if you just access it directly with that url in a browser or some other way?

Comment: @DougStevenson when I access URL from browser, the file is downloaded. So, the "Public" access part is working. I set the SSLCERT option in node-libcurl to pick the cert from this URL when doing cURL call. This is not happening (based on error message).

Comment: Another thing I noticed is, when I do a plain cURL from a Linux command line to this URL, it fails with `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`. However, cURL succeeds in another machine (MacOS). Linux has cURL version 7.47.0 while MacOS has 7.54.0.

Comment: Most likely you have not installed cacert.pem on your local machine: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html Download cacert.pem: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem